# Measuring duration and distances between pulses

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rf, frequency, signal

I want to know how it is done (or at least how would you do) to measure duration and distances between pulses on a signal in a micro controller(or a better way).

Example: I have a couple of Arduinos and a couple of this RF Transmitter/Receivers(http://bit.ly/oT05Qg) and have a protocol setup that says I'm supposed to receive 4 bits (1111) with duration of 0,5 micro seconds and the space between them as of 1,5 micro seconds. If it is any different, I should ignore the information.

How can I/would you do this?

P.S: The best example in real life I could find was this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Interrogation.jpg

Comment: FYI, the documentation in the linked device makes use of an Arduino library called "VirtualWire". The easy answer is to use that, but I think this is a good question anyways and a chance to learn how to use timer interrupts or any other solution that gets posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I certainly wouldn't be trying to do this with a Arduino (remember, you asked what *I* would do).  Measuring characteristics of pulses at 500 kHz rate is going to be tricky.  The big question you left open is how close does it need to be, or more accurately, how close to you need to know it is to the perfect 500 ns and 1.5 µs timings?  If you need to know this to within 1%, for example, then it's going to be difficult and get quite expensive.

If it's good enough to sample the signal every 250 ns and live with the resulting uncertainty in timing, then it's easier but still tricky.  In that case you could sample the signal into a shift register at 4 MHz, then analyze the result in firmware.  Generting a 4 MHz clock output with most advanced micros is easy, and many will have a SPI peripheral that can be repurposed to a serial to parallel converter.

On a processor like a PIC 24H, the instruction rate can go to 40 MHz.  That only leaves 10 instruction on average per bit to process, which sounds too little for this method to be workable.

Another approach is to gate counters on for the high and low times, and thereby get a count of the number of clock ticks between edges.  You still have 1M edges per second to deal with, or 40 instructions per edge.  That still sounds tight, but possibly doable depending on what else you need to do and what has to be done with the result.  The 24H has "input capture" modules that do most of this in hardware, but the firmware still has to make sense of the resulting duration measurements.

Note that your pulse train has a average level of 1/4, which might be possible to exploit with some cleverness and depending on what else is going on, how fast you need it, and a lot of other things you haven't said.

Comment: Now, would it be better if I raise the frequency to, say, 1030MHz?

And answering your question: I believe I might have a certain margin on the accuracy, but not too much. My guess is it has to be around 95% accurate on the timing.

Answer (score 0):

Many asynchronous serial communication schemes, like RS232, involve a known idle/mark state of the line and a start signal/bit as well stop bit(s). Oversampling the RX line allows one to sync up to the middle of the start bits in the middle and finally  sample each of the bit and validate the state of the stop bits.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_serial_communication

Answer (score 0):

There is an Arduino [function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn) specifically designed to measure pulse length:

```
pulseIn(pin, value)
pulseIn(pin, value, timeout)
```

However, it is not suitable for your purposes as the detectable pulse length range is 10 microseconds to 3 minutes. Also, once the measurement is done, you will have to process the result (at the very least store it somewhere), which takes time and may make you miss the start of the next pulse.

You may be able to measure shorter pulses by setting an ISR to the pin with

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), ISR, mode);
```

and using `micros()` function which has a resolution of 4 microseconds, but that's as far as you can get. Arduino is simply not fast enough to measure shorter pulses without special hardware. The most promising would be to use SPI if your boards have it, but it will only work if you receive pulses in groups which could be mapped to SPI transactions.